# get the number from a line of html code using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i get the number inside a html code.

For example:

```
<a href="#">Comments</a>(10)
```

How can i get the 10 from the line of code above.

This includes removing the link html , comment word , plus the brackets around the number "10"

How can do this using jquery/javascript?

Comment: Can you provide the containing html element?(dom structure)

Comment: the line above is extracted from a html page and stored in a javascript variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given html

```
<a id="#element" href="#">Comments</a>(10)
```

jQuery:

```
var value = $("#element").get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue; //"(10)"
value = parseFloat( value.substr(1) ); //10
```

If you have a string (`'<a href="#">Comments</a>(10)'`), then

```
var value = $('<div>', {html: '<a href="#">Comments</a>(10)'}).contents().get(1).nodeValue; //"(10)"
value = parseFloat( value.substr(1) ); //10
```

Comment: but the brackets is there (10)

Comment: @sm21guy `parseFloat("(10)".substr(1)) === 10`

Comment: must there be === 10 because the value 10 is just an example , the numbers im getting varies

Comment: @sm21guy no, my comment was an example how to turn `"(number)"` into `number`. The equality is provided so you can see what the result would be and you could confirm it directly by copy pasting it in a console.

Comment: it is able to get the (10) but it when i parseFloat it , the output value is NaN

Comment: @sm21guy Are you reading my code? It says `parseFloat( value.substr(1) )`. You are doing `parseFloat( value )`. See the difference?

Comment: `parseFloat( value.substr(1) )` yes im doing this.

Comment: @sm21guy please provide a jsfiddle because I already prooved my code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/yjEkp/

Comment: @sm21guy that's my jsfiddle and it's working... you said it returns NaN but it doesn't. Show me a jsfiddle where you get NaN so I can see what's wrong...

Comment: @sm21guy your html has `</a> (10)` NOT `</a>(10)`. Try `.substr(2)` http://jsfiddle.net/yjEkp/3/

Comment: @sm21guy be sure you *understand* why you needed substr with 2. This site is not really about getting free coding work done but educating.

Comment: yes i understand now. 1 is to get the first character , 2 is to get the second character , as there is a space between , so substr(2) to get the second character which is the bracket (

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
http://pastebin.com/PV9f0PQH

I paste example in pastebin because here is problems when paste part of html tags.